# Database Tagging with alternative Results

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I'm working on an PHP/Jquery autosuggest tool that'll query a large table of tags but I need 
some suggestions for the db schema that'll return related tags as well as match-based results.

For example:

I type 'Web':

Results

**'Web Developer'**

**'Web Designer'**

**'Web Analyst'**

and also related tags...

**'PHP Developer'**

'**Flash Programmer'**

So obviously there needs to be a column for each tag with some sort of relational or parentage value... Whats the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

--- UPDATE -----------------

certainly - and thanks again for all your help!

here are the tables..

### Tags

Id  TagName

1   Web Developer

2   Web Designer

3   Web Analyst

4   PHP Developer

5   Flash Programmer

### RelatedTags

TagId RelatedTagId Strength

1   4       0

1   5       7

Since the Strength value of 'Flash Programmer' is 7 i'd like it to appear before PHP programmer..(hopefully the format is clear enough..)

thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Table Tags

```
Create Table Tags (Id int, TagName varchar(50))
```

Table RelatedTags (both fields FK to Tags(Id) )

```
Create Table RelatedTags(TagId int, RelatedTagId int)
```

Query for selecting tag matched input and related tags

```
SELECT Id, TagName, Strength
FROM Tags
WHERE TagName LIKE 'Web%'
UNION
SELECT Id, TagName, Strength
FROM Tags 
WHERE tags.Id IN (SELECT RelatedTagId
       FROM Tags t
       JOIN RelatedTags r
       ON (t.Id = r.TagId)
       WHERE t.tagName LIKE 'Web%')
ORDER By 3 DESC
```

Comment: that looks great... though i'm getting a syntax error (near 'SELECT RelatedTagId FROM Tags t JOIN RelatedTags r ON (t.Id' at line 7) 0 - i cant see it ;(

Comment: wait nevermind... got it... excellent - looks brill - thanks!

Comment: so i've added a 'Strength' column (SMALLINT) to the related table... I'm going to use this specify the ordering of results based on the closeness of the match - for example I want Flash to appear before PHP... I give Flash a strength of 7 and PHP 4 - so where do i put the ordering clause?

Comment: tried this but know it wasnt right - 

SELECT Id, TagName
FROM Tags
WHERE TagName LIKE 'Web%'
UNION
SELECT Id, TagName
FROM Tags 
WHERE Tags.Id IN (SELECT RelatedTagId
       FROM Tags t
       JOIN RelatedTags r
       ON (t.Id = r.TagId)
       WHERE t.tagName LIKE 'Web%')
 ORDER BY r.Strength DESC

Comment: @Fearghal, added Strength field into query

Comment: Hi Michael... sorry - the strength column is in the RelatedTags table which the above sql can't find... is it a matter of simply adding the relatedTags table to the initial SELECT statement? thanks for your help

Comment: @Fearghal, can you explain in details how you want sort results?

Comment: sure... i'll put it in a current post for formatting purposes